# How can i browse a text file in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, ios-simulator

How can i browse a text file in iPhone ?.

I used `UIImagePickerController`, but can only browse in photo library, but i want to browse whole phone memory just like `asp:fileupload`.

Thanks.

Comment: you can do that only on jail broken ios devices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can however browse files in your app's own documents folder, by retrieving directory listings via the NSFileManager. You can't however browse the directories holding files for other apps. This is due to Apple's sandboxing of apps for security.